# Setting a cookie from a select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie form a select form at the click of a button using jQuery, but I got kind of stuck. I am not that experienced with jQuery but everything seems ok to me, but obviously isn't because it is not working.
You can see my piece of code below.

HTML:

```
<select id="defaultFormat">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<a href='/' id='setCookie'>GO</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#setCookie').click(function() {
    var value = $("#defaultFormat").val();
    $.cookie("defFormat", value, { expires: 365 });
    });
```

Comment: Well, for starters, your select has an id of "default" not "defaultFormat".

Comment: Also, using `$.cookie()` depends on having the jQuery cookie plugin installed -- do you?

Comment: @JacobM Was just a typo when I wrote it down here, the document has the right id. And yes, I have the plugin, no errors in chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#setCookie').click(function() {
    var value = $("#defaultFormat").val();
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 365);
    document.cookie = "defFormat="+value +"; expires="+ date.toGMTString() +"; path=/";
});
```

Comment: It's the same with this.